# Windows server and AWS clock synchronization

Tags: windows, ntp, clock-synchronization

I have a Windows 7 computer that communicates with Amazon Web Servers (S3, SES). This server uses windows internet time for clock synchronization `time.windows.com`. On my linux machines I ran into clock drifting issues that caused S3 URLs to expire sooner than they should and kept SES from sending emails. I fixed this by installing and running `ntpd`

Questions:

- Does Windows `internet time settings` operate over `NTP`?
- Will I run into clock drifting issues by using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Windows internet time settings operate over NTP?

Yes.

> Will I run into clock drifting issues by using it?

Assuming you're using a stable time source and you have things configured correctly, no, this should prevent drift.

Comment: It defaults to `time.windows.com` Will this work? Everything is UTC time so I'm not worried about timezone issues.

Comment: It is generally advised to add at least 3 NTP servers as time sources. Find a couple more from the public [NTP pool](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/).